# Detect and respond to ping in userspace

Tags: linux, networking, scripting

Is there a way to make a linux system react or do something when pinged from another device, besides just sending a reply (or not)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Linux netfilter to intercept incoming pings and send them to userspace. This will do it:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j NFLOG
```

You can add any kind of iptables criteria like `-s` (source) in order to intercept only some pings and not others.

Note that this does not cancel the kernel's handling of the original ping. It only sends a copy to userspace. If you plan to respond to the ping from userspace then you will want to prevent the kernel from also handling it so that there are not 2 replies. To implement that, just follow up the above with another iptables rule to drop the original:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP
```

In order to receive the ping from userspace, you have to write some C code. The [libnetfilter_log library](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_log/) is what you need. Here is some sample code which I wrote a few years ago that does exactly that:

```
#include <libnetfilter_log/libnetfilter_log.h>
[...]

    struct nflog_handle *h;
    struct nflog_g_handle *qh;
    ssize_t rv;
    char buf[4096];

    h = nflog_open();
    if (!h) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error during nflog_open()\n");
            return 1;
    }
    if (nflog_unbind_pf(h, AF_INET) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error nflog_unbind_pf()\n");
            return 1;
    }
    if (nflog_bind_pf(h, AF_INET) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error during nflog_bind_pf()\n");
            return 1;
    }
    qh = nflog_bind_group(h, 0);
    if (!qh) {
            fprintf(stderr, "no handle for group 0\n");
            return 1;
    }

    if (nflog_set_mode(qh, NFULNL_COPY_PACKET, 0xffff) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "can't set packet copy mode\n");
            return 1;
    }

    nflog_callback_register(qh, &callback, NULL);

    fd = nflog_fd(h);

    while ((rv = recv(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)) && rv >= 0) {
            nflog_handle_packet(h, buf, rv);
    }
```

`callback` is a function that gets called for each incoming packet. It is defined as something like this:

```
static int
callback(struct nflog_g_handle *gh, struct nfgenmsg *nfmsg, struct nflog_data *ldata, void *data)
{
    payload_len = nflog_get_payload(ldata, (char **)(&ip));
    ....
    /* now "ip" points to the packet's IP header */
    /* ...do something with it... */
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way I would use is to sniff ICMP traffic by any utility (wireshark, tcpdump, iptables etc.).
For example, you can use the following approach: [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/448541/how-to-know-who-ping-my-computer)

Comment: Thank you, I've read the answers in the question you linked, but I do not quite understand how to use this to make my system "do" something whenever it is pinged. What I imagine is something like an alarm that goes off once it has been pinged by an unknown IP.

Comment: Well, let's see. You can redirect output of any program to file (by using >> operator) or to pipe. Then you can write a simple script (or program in C) which checks mtime and number of lines in the file (or gets information from the pipe) and alarms.

Comment: Okay, thank you, thats just the help I needed - didn't think of that.

Comment: Better yet: use an intrusion detection system such as [snort](https://www.snort.org/).  You'd have to spend some time learning it though.

Comment: Yes, I found Snort and some other already existing solutions like MHN, but they seem to be quite complex. I'll take a look at them though. Thank you.